# Hibernate JPQL Update/Delete operations inside a transaction

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Using Hibernate (4.2.7.SP1), Spring and Oracle. Noticed that when the last line in the method (JPQL UPDATE) is executed, but before the @Transactional methods ends, dev's name *A* is commited to the database and it is visible(in selects from another connection)!

```java
    @Transactional
    public void doInTransaction()
    {

      User user = userDao.findById("dev");

      user.setName("A");

      userDao.getEntityManager().createQuery("UPDATE User set name='B'").executeUpdate();
    }
```

Note that User is a subclass of Person, InheritanceType.JOINED, i.e. there are two tables involved, the *name* field is inherited from Person.

Found some information here http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/MultitableBulkOperations explaining how hibernate performs the UPDATES and DELETES, and that for inheritance tables it creates temporary tables prefixed with *HT_*.

Performed some debugging, the issue as I see it can be represented in two lines:

```sql
    update ILC_PERSON set name = 'A';

    create global temporary table HT_ILC_PERSON_USER (id varchar2(255 char) not null) on commit delete rows;

    -- bellow should execute the JPQL UPDATE User set name='B'
```

What happens is that when the DDL for creating the temporary table is executed, oracle commits automatically the previous DML.

**Question:**

- is this a Hibernate bug?
- is there some misconfiguration in the project (using LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with JpaTransactionManager)?
- does this simple means we cannot use JPQL UPDATE/DELETES for entities with InheritanceType.JOINED in one transaction?
- something else?